# Globally override default type attribute for <button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

According to W3 Schools ([Link 1](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_type.asp) [Link 2](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)), the `<button>` tag's `type` attribute defaults to `'submit'` for *most* browsers. I want to change this for my website so whenever I leave out the `type` attribute on a `<button>`, it defaults to `type='button'` instead.

I wrote the following Javascript and placed it in a file included by all webpages:

```
$(function() {

  // Select all buttons without a type explicitly set, and give them a default type.
  $('button:not([type])').prop('type', 'button');

});
```

Of course, this isn't a great fix. Any `<button>` elements I dynamically generate without setting the type explicitly will default to `type='submit'` (for most browsers).

Is there some other solution to this? Maybe some sort of `<meta>` tag I can use?

**EDIT:** There is another solution.

My page was set up with a `<form>` element surrounding most of the page. I then had a `<button>` inside the form which was intended to dynamically create textboxes, which themselves were hooked up to an `<input type='hidden'>` through some Javascript magic. I also had several normal, static `<input type='text'>` sprinkled throughout the page that were intended to be submitted along with the form. The one true `<button type='submit'>` is at the bottom of the page.

What I can do is restructure my page such that the `<form>` only surrounds the `<button>` at the bottom of the page, and then hook in all the elements I want included with the submission using their `form` property, like such:

```
<button>Generate dynamic textbox</button>
<!-- Generated textboxes go here... -->
<input type='hidden' name='dynamicTextboxAccumulation' form='breakfast_menu'>

<input type='text' name='order' value='spam' form='breakfast_menu'>

<form id='breakfast_menu' action='/order/place' method='post'>
  <button type='submit'>Place Order</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What issues are you facing if your buttons have `type=submit`?

Comment: I have a form with dynamically-generated text boxes that altogether map to a `<input type='hidden'>`. The user can press a button to add another text box to the form. The issue is, this button element is also present inside the `<form>` so the browser interprets it as a command to submit the form.

Comment: So you cannot take the button out of the form?

Comment: Not really, unless there is some way to have multiple `<form>` tags be considered one when it comes time to submit to the server.

Comment: Actually I just discovered something. HTML5 introduced the `form` attribute for `<input>` elements. I can simply surround my `<button type='submit'>` with a `<form>` element, then use the `form` attribute to link these disparate elements to the form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually write better answers than this so forgive me for this one...

Nope.

Any HTML element attribute and its value is left up to the browser to interpret. The only option is to explicitly set the `type`.

Comment: Well that sucks. I suppose I'll have to avoid dynamically generating `<button>` elements, or switch over to `<input type='button'>`. Thank you :)

Comment: well you can still dynamically generate them, just generate them with the correct `type`